# How to deal with low gpu utilization

Tags: pytorch, gpu, yolov5

[when training YOLOv5, GPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TMKF.png)
I want to use fully GPU
So i checked and correct "number of workers",anything i can do
but my GPU did not work fully
please help me before crash my computer

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your network (I call it `yolo_network`) to CUDA

```
yolo_network.to('cuda')
```

Comment: very very very very useless